# How can fix HDMI HDTV overscan when I my TV has no aspect ratio setting?

Tags: intel-graphics, resolution, tv, hdmi, hd-video

I have a 32" Vizio HDTV. It's a few years old, but running well. I just connected a new nettop to it using HDMI out. It's the Intel 3x00 graphics chipset.

I'm seeing overscan, where the resolution in Ubuntu is set to 1280x720, but the TV itself is 1366x768. When I go into the **Monitors** control applet, I cannot change the resolution to anything other than the current or 640x480.

A user had a similar overscan problem, but [fixed the overscan by adjusting his TV's aspect ratio settings](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4358/how-do-i-fix-overscan-on-my-hdmi-hdtv). I do not have that luxury.

Is there a way I can do this without having to delve into `xorg.conf` or other command-line craziness? I'm more than comfortable doing so, but *there must be a cleaner way*.

I'm running Ubuntu Natty, keeping up with updates and such.

Here's the output of lspci:

```
colin@bricktop:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 12)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 12)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor Thermal Management Controller (rev 12)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset HECI Controller (rev 06)
00:1a.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 06)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio (rev 06)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev 06)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev 06)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev 06)
00:1d.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 06)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev a6)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 5 Series Chipset LPC Interface Controller (rev 06)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset 4 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 06)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset SMBus Controller (rev 06)
00:1f.6 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset Thermal Subsystem (rev 06)
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 06)
02:00.0 USB Controller: NEC Corporation uPD720200 USB 3.0 Host Controller (rev 03)
03:00.0 Network controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR9287 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be able to use `xrandr` to add a new mode to the specific output and then select that new mode.  See `xrandr --addmode` and `xrandr --mode` in the xrandr manpage.

Comment: I think this is the most correct. I tried this and IIRC it worked. I no longer have the TV, though -- replaced it with a 1920x1080 47".

Answer (score 1):

It would seem a bit weird for a TV to have 768 lines: HDTVs are usually 720 or 1080 lines, so if the computer thinks the screen is 720 lines I'd be inclined to think it is correct.

Is it possible that the TV itself has some options to scale the input?  Check to see if there is a "full pixel" or "100%" option, or something similar that will let the display the image over the full screen.

Comment: Many TVs have displays which are actually 1366x768.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try the --pos option of xrandr. See the answer from Vadim Rutkovsky to this question:
[Geforce GT240M: How to disable Notebook screen and enable external Monitor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26475/geforce-gt240m-how-to-disable-notebook-screen-and-enable-external-monitor)