# Geforce GT240M: How to disable Notebook screen and enable external Monitor

Tags: video, nvidia, hdmi

When i attach my Notebook (Nvidia Geforce GT 240M) to my Panasonic-TV via HDMI, both screens are activated. I use Nvidia-Driver Version 260.19.06.

I wonder how to deactivate my notebook display automatically or with one Script and switch to the external Monitor when attached. The TV needs an overscan-correction of 100px to display the whole screen.

I also want to close the notebook without deactivating the external monitor, what still happens now.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So at least i found a solution for my problem.

What i found out is, that xrandr is nor supported by the propietary NVIDIA-drvers. Xrandr even can't detect my displays. The nvidia tool nvidia-settings can be used from command line, but is not capable to activate or deactivate screens.

To switch displays you can use the tool disper: [disper on launchpad](https://launchpad.net/disper)
It's a command line tools, wich exactly fits my problem an is easy to use.

Some example scripts for automatic switching at startup can be found here: [Ubuntuusers.de wiki](http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Disper)

Hope, that this may help someone.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple script to turn off notebook display when external monitor is connected:

```
if xrandr -q | grep -q  "HDMI connected"; then
  xrandr --output LVDS --off --output DFP1
else
  xrandr --output VGA --off --output LVDS
fi
```

If you want to set a specific resolution, you may add "--mode 1680x1050" in the end of xrandr lines. 
Output offset can be added using "--pos 100x0" command.

The script can be bound to any unused key combination or executed on startup using "System>>Preferences>>Startup Applications"

Note, that "DFP1" may be different on your system - check out 'xrandr -q' output with external monitor attached

Comment: Thank you, i will try this at home. So if i want an overscan correction of 100px from a 1920x108 resolution, i have to add: --mode 1820x950 --pos100x100? And how can i prevent my notebook to disable display when closing the lid?

Comment: `--mode` and `--pos` are indepndent - set mode to 1920x1080 and pos to 100x100 or whatever you need. You may to calibrate these values, trying them in Terminal.

Comment: After notebook display is off, the lid won't blank both displays

Comment: With xandr i get the following message: 
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 175, current 1366 x 768, maximum 1366 x 768
default connected 1366x768+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1366x768       50.0* 
... So my Panasonic can't be detected. Nvidia-Settings recognizes it correctly. What can i do?

Comment: @bdr529, it seems, that maximum available resolution is 1366x768, so replace '1920x1080' with '1366x768' (I guess, that is actual for LVDS string)

Answer (score 1):

Graphical gtk tool to do the same thing: [grandr](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grandr). It's in the official repos so you can

```
sudo apt-get install grandr
```