# Display Problem

Tags: display

Having just installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my Novatech laptop, I find that 
all display content is larger than it should be. 
When displaying a single page, I cannot view the extremes as they are 
outside the viewable area of the screen.

I tried to see if I could solve the problem by changing the display
resolution (in System Settings) but there were no alternative options 
to choose from.

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/4358/how-do-i-fix-overscan-on-my-hdmi-hdtv and http://filthypants.blogspot.co.uk/2013/03/xrandr-overscan-fix-for-intel-hd4000.html may help.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if I got it right. Is the resolution problem related to external display? If it is maybe this will help:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=945465