# How to set screen borders for HDMI output

Tags: xorg, tv

Is there a way to set the screen borders manually? Right now, when I have it connected to my TV via HDMI, the edges of the screen are cut off. It looks something like this that I found from another question:

[image: As you can see, the launcher is cut off]

Card: AMD Radeon HD 4890
TV: Panasonic th-50px60u

Comment: change your TV settings, something "Fit screen"

Comment: My TV doesn't have a setting like that unfortunately

Comment: see http://askubuntu.com/questions/4358/how-do-i-fix-overscan-on-my-hdmi-hdtv

Comment: I have a older Panasonic TV, which like I JUST said, doesn't have a setting like that.

Comment: change the  resulation with custome one http://askubuntu.com/questions/377937/how-to-set-a-custom-resolution

Comment: Setting the resolution doesn't matter, still has edges cut off.

Comment: I had a bad cable that would cause 1920x1080 to expand outside a 1920x1080 monitor. I set the resolution to to something lower. Problem bypassed.

Comment: @bmazoka take a look at my answer - it's not really related to resolution.

Comment: @VolkerSiegel as OP noted in [this comment](http://askubuntu.com/questions/526836/set-screen-resolution?noredirect=1#comment717926_526836), no overscan. :(

Comment: I'd still strongly suspect a bad cable or port. @VolkerSiegel you can delete comments regarding the edit now.

Comment: @muru Hmm.. he said "older TV" - that does not sound like it has no overscan.

Comment: Can you add your own screenshot, model of your TV and graphic card.

Comment: Updated the information

Comment: On page 15 of the [Owner's manual](http://service.us.panasonic.com/OPERMANPDF/TH37PX60U-ENGLISH.PDF) "overscan" is called "zoom" on your TV.  Could you verify all different zoom settings and report back?  That was the solution on my Panasonic TV...

Answer (score 46, accepted):

What you are looking at is a feature called ***"overscan"*** (or "zoom" on some TVs). It's the TV itself cutting off the edges!

***So, look for a feature called overscan (or zoom) in the setup of the TV, and disable it!***

**Some history:**

Long time ago, when cathode ray tubes - CRTs - were used as television displays, and the images were transferred in an analogue way, it had a technical reason, it was useful.
The TV stations were used to always have a border with nothing important in it.

With pixel matrix displays like LCD, overscan no longer makes sense.
But people are used to have it, and think it's better to have the feature than not have it.

If you want to sell LCD TVs, you have customers asking for it, and because it costs nothing to provide it, you better list that feature in the description.

It will not do any harm, no problem. Except if someone enables it.

Comment: Correct, to the point, complete **and the answer to the question!!**  And still you get two downvotes without comment.  This was exactly the solution for my TV! (One upvote from me! And an edit)

Comment: Oh, thanks! I was starting to think I somehow missed the point and better delete the answer. Maybe it's just that I could not convince the OP that his TV has an overscan setting at all.

Comment: Ah, just noticed you found the overscan setting in the manual - but with a different name than "overscan" - oh, I explicitly wrote "called overscan" - will fix that.

Comment: Done already!!!  :D :D :D

Comment: It's work for me (Condor TV)

Comment: thank you, amazing. I scratched my head forever on this for my Asus pb287q.

Comment: That's not answer to the question! Question is how to set screen borders with xorg, not how to disable overscan on TV! My old TV has no option to disable overscan and I MUST ADD MARGINS on my PC connected to tv, I found this topic and no any usable answer.

Comment: On my Sony TV, I had to set Settings -> Screen -> Display Area to "Full Pixel"

Comment: long live stack exchange

Answer (score 6):

My TV also does that. Usually I just run

```
xrandr --output LVDS1 --primary --auto --output HDMI1 --auto --same-as LVDS1
```

This fixes the wrong resolution on the monitor, making it a **mirror** of my laptop.

I have this command conveniently aliased to something I can remember:

```
alias xrandr-hdmi-mirror="xrandr --output LVDS1 --primary --auto --output HDMI1 --auto --same-as LVDS1"
```

This way I just run `xrandr-hdmi-mirror` whenever I connect my TV.

Of course, you should adjust HDMI1 and/or LVDS1 to your system. Run `xrandr` to discover which device you should use.

---

## Updated answer

Since you have only one monitor (your TV) try the following:

1. Discover the output name of your TV. It is probably `HDMI1` or `VGA1`. To do it, run `xrandr` then search for the word "connected". For example, if you see `HDM1 connected`, then your TV is `HDMI1`.
2. Try doing a `xrandr --output HDMI1 --auto`. See if the resolution gets okay.
3. If not, you'll have to do a `xrandr --output HDMI1 --mode 1024x768`, for example. However, you should replace `1024x768` to a resolution that your TV supports. The output of `xrandr` will tell you the available ones.

Comment: Problem with your method is I am ONLY using the TV as a monitor. There isn't anything for me to compare it to or set as the same.

Comment: OK, in this case, try the following:  (still editing, hit enter too soon)

1. Run xrandr to discover the name assigned to uour monitor. It is probably VGA1 or HDMI1.

Comment: Alright, whats the next step?

Comment: I've updated my original answer.

Comment: Tried auto and it was the one I was currently on. Then I tried all the resolutions it listed and each one still was cutting off edges.

Comment: Then I recommend you to explore the manpage of xrandr. Maybe the options 'panning', 'pos' and 'transform' might help you. As a temporary measure, you might try `xrandr --output HDMI1 --auto --panning 2200x2200`. This way your screen will still be cut, however you will be able to move your mouse where it is cut, then the screen will move with it. To disable this behavior, just pass to the panning parameter your original resolution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17323/discussion-between-bmazoka-and-thiagowfx).

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem with my Samsung TV connecting to my laptop via HDMI and found the solution by going to the TV Menu > Picture > Screen Adjustment > chose "screen fit" that fixed it. There you will find other options too but for me the screen fit did the trick and that over scan issue was fixed.

All this time i was thinking it was the display setting on the Ubuntu laptop i needed to fix. Hope This helps other.

Comment: Thanks, that was my problem too.  On my TV, it was under "aspect ratio" > "just scan"

Comment: Helped me samsung s22c200

Answer (score 2):

For LG TV's (webOS 4, Software Version 05.30.10)

All Settings > Picture > Aspect Ratio Settings > Just Scan > On

Although you might experience performance issues when running on a 4K resolution screen with the maximized app window, the app runs smoothly if you scale the app window down a little bit.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem. The `xrandr` info in other answers didn't help in my case, but it was good background anyway.  I fixed the problem on my screen by resetting the aspect ratio setting back to 1:1.  It had somehow been changed to "wide".

Comment: You changed it on the tv not computer?

Answer (score 1):

Samsung TV:

Tools -> Image Size (change from 16:9 to adjust screen).

If you have another TV or monitor you just search for your model in google/youtube with overscan or zoom image mode

Answer (score 1):

Switch Your TV-settings to the `4:3` format. Now You see two black blocks left and right beside the desktop margins. If a third of ubuntu's control panel is cut off now, You can be sure of that the problem is not Your TV.

Answer (score -1):

Guys there is simple solution to it using panasonic TV. In the Advanced Settings, turn the overscan off. This fixes the problem

Comment: This is a duplicate of the top voted [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/526839/767056)