# How To Launch Activities menu? What is the Super key?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, display

In poking around trying to make sense of this new 20.04 LTS installation, I can't seem to bring up the Activities screen.  The doc says to press the Super key.  OK - I'm using a standard Windows keyboard - WHAT is the Super key?  I was pressing the key with the Window on it, but that just brings up a search menu.  Ctrl and Alt by themselves don't work, and the hot-corners don't work either, AND I can't find out from Settings whether they are even defined.

One thing may be causing a problem.  I'm using an LG TV as a monitor connected to a Dell 790 via an HDMI cable. It sees like the Ubuntu driver is making the screen image a little too large for the surface area of the TV screen, because the dock at the bottom is cut off (it's visible, but only the top 2/3 of the icons show) and the top bar with the date on it doesn't display at all.  I only discovered it was there when I set the display scale to 200%.  This is not a problem I had with this TV when it was connected to a Mac Mini.

Comment: The key with the Windows logo is the Super key.

Comment: Not all notebooks have a windows logo there. I have  a penguin :) "I was pressing the key with the Window on it, but that just brings up a search menu" that is the activities menu. You can start typing and it will show in real time what matches,. ALT + F1 is the equivalent of the super key.

Comment: The problem with the LG TV is resolved.  It was a TV issue.  See this post:   https://askubuntu.com/questions/4358/how-do-i-fix-overscan-on-my-hdmi-hdtv

Answer (score 0):

The super key is the key with the windows logo on it(most commonly). Super key opens activity search, and if you want to open the activities menu , use the shortcut `Super+A`