# Is there any utility in kde plasma 5 (Kubuntu) to quickly adjust the resolution to the TV (overscan)?

Tags: kubuntu, display, hdmi, overscan

I am using an old TV as a monitor, and as is common with hdmi connections to these devices, I am having problems with overscan (the resolution options are reduced and the edges of the screen are cut off, making it impossible to correctly access the desktop and windows).

In Ubuntu there is a solution implemented that is wonderfully simple (Settings > Display > Adjust to TV).

However, in Kubuntu I simply could not find a solution, let alone a simple one...

Does anyone know of a simple method like Ubuntu's to solve overscan problems in Kubuntu?

Comment: Most TVs can be adjusted in itself. Try that instead if you don't find what you're looking for in Kubuntu. Please note that the function "adjust to TV" has been introduced in 21.04. This "problem" precedes that release by more than a decade. Users have been solving it way before there were such feature.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, ChanganAuto. Unfortunately, I have tried all the options on the TV, without success. I have tried several methods to solve the problem, but none have worked yet, except for the Ubuntu feature.

Comment: Had you used *any* previous release you'd have the same problem. Some Nvidia cards allow adjustments at Nvidia X Server Settings. Other than that you may need to use xrandr or something. PS - Not an answer, it's posted as comment.

Comment: From what I have researched, this issue is easier to solve with Nvidia and AMD hardware. Unfortunately, I am using a notebook with Intel graphics.I have tried several methods with xrandr, but nothing works with my hardware. Since I use Kubuntu, and used Ubuntu 21.04 on a USB stick for testing, I didn't know that the implementation of the "Fit to TV" solution was so recent. Since it was implemented in Ubuntu, I was wondering if in Kubuntu they would have implemented something like that as well.

Comment: As many would say - it most cases that's TV issue and you simply need to disable overscan/wide/cinema modes on the TV. See this question for TV model details hints: [How do I fix overscan on my HDMI HDTV?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4358/how-do-i-fix-overscan-on-my-hdmi-hdtv)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `kscreen-doctor`. It is shipped with KDE, so must be available on Kubuntu.

First get the display name. Following commands outputs all connected displays:

```
kscreen-doctor --outputs
```

Position the HDMI monitor on the right of the laptop panel while leaving eDP-1 on the left:

```
$ kscreen-doctor output.HDMI-2.position.0,1280 output.eDP-1.position.0,0
```

Here, eDP-1 will be on the left, HDMI-2 on the right starting at 1280.

Set resolution and refresh rate for a screen:

```
$ kscreen-doctor output.HDMI-2.mode.1920x1080@60
```